# Laravel One To Many relationship (Players and Team)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, one-to-many

I'm trying to create some relationships with my tables (Player and Team), but I can't display my team's name with the player associate.

**Guideline** : A team has many players. The foreignkey (TEA_ID) is on the player table.

Here is my Team Model (**Team.php**)

```
class Team extends Model
{
protected $table = 'teams';
protected $primaryKey ='TEA_ID';

public function players(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Player');
}

}
```

Here is a part of my template (**players.blade.php**)

```
 <?php
        foreach($players as $player) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $player->PLA_ID?></td>
        <td><?php echo $player->PLA_Name?></td>
        <td><?php echo $player->PLA_Surname?></td>
        <td><?php echo $player->PLA_Pseudo?></td>
        @if($player->team)
            <td><?php echo $player->team->TEA_NAME?></td>
        @endif
        <td>|<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>|</td>
        <td>|<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDelete"></span>|</td>
    </tr>
```

Here is my Controller of player (**PlayerController.php**)

```
public function show(){ // reçoit l'url http://monsite.fr/users avec le     verbe "get" et qui retourne le formulaire.

    $players = player::with('team')->get();
    return view('players', ['players' => $players]);

}
```

Here is the Player Model (**Player.php**)

```
class Player extends Model
{
protected $table = 'players';
protected $primaryKey ='PLA_ID';


public function team(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Team');
}

}
```

The table playes displays datas correctly, but not the team's name. I know I can use the belongsTo() method but I don't know where's my error. Thank you for your help, I will learn a lot =)

Comment: where is your Player Model?

Comment: Excuse me, here is the model, but I worked specially on the Team Model for the relationship.

Comment: You really need to set `belongTo()` relationship in your Player Model. if you want `$player->team->TEA_NAME` to works.

Comment: and remeber if you are not using `team_id` as foreign key in that relation, and also `id` as default primary key in your table, you need to set up the key manually in the relationship method. Look at the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 0):

You should define the relationship with Team in your Player model:

```
class Player extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'players';
    protected $primaryKey ='PLA_ID';

    public function team() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Team');
    }

}
```

Then you'll be able to access the Team data in this way:
(Assuming $player is an instance of Player model)

```
$player->team->TEA_NAME
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: @Follio said the same but it doesn't work, but I'm reading the docs about One to May.

Comment: You should do some debug. I don't understand why you use player::with('team')->get(); The function show() should get a param with the Team ID, then you load an instance of Team so you can return $team->players to the view.